# Converting multivariable functions to spherical coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

I'm trying to evaluate the integral: $${\int_0}^1 {\int_0}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}} {\int_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}^{\sqrt{2-x^2-y^2}}} xy \space dxdydz$$

by converting to spherical coordinates.

I've got the equations of the surfaces:

$z^2 = x^2 + y^2$ $\space (1)$

$2=z^2 +x^2 +y^2$ $\space (2)$

$x=0$ $\space (3)$

$y=0$ $\space (4)$

and I want to convert these to spherical coordinates (in order for me to re-write the integral above as an integral with spherical coordinates).

I know that to convert to spherical coordinates:

$x=r \cos\rho \sin\theta$, $y=r \sin\rho \sin\theta$, $z=r \cos\theta$

So I substituted these values into my $4$ above equations but I was confused on how to simplify them.

I checked my answer sheet (which has no working out provided) and these are the answers they give:

$(1): r^2 \cos^2 \rho = r^2 \sin^2 \rho$

$(2): r=\sqrt 2$

$(3): \theta = \pi /2$

$(4): \theta = 0$

I have no idea how these were obtained with equations I have and the transformations I listed, maybe I did the simplification wrong but if anyone could show me how these spherical coordinates were obtained it would really help.

I think I subbed my $x,y,z$ values in and simplified wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try? Can you show?

Comment: What do you get for $z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$  and $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 2$  using $x = \rho \cos\theta \sin\phi, y = \rho \sin \theta \sin\phi, z = \rho \cos\phi$?

Comment: @MathLover Sorry for the late reply, my internet went down for over an hour :/ What I did was literally just sub in the values so for example my equation $(1)$ looks like this now: $r^2 \space cos^2 \rho \space sin^2 \theta + r^2 \space sin^2 \rho \space sin^2 \theta = r^2 \space cos^2 \theta$ and I'm not sure how they went from that to what I've put above.

Comment: Equation $(2)$ looks like this: I changed $2 = x^2 + z^2 +y^2$ to $\sqrt{2} = x + y + z$ and so I got $\sqrt{2} = r \space cos \rho \space sin \theta + r \space sin \theta \space sin \rho + r \space cos \theta$

Comment: I'm just not sure how they're removing certain terms, for example, in equation $(2)$ only $r$ is supposedly left behind, but how did they remove terms like $cos \theta$ that I can't see any way of removing to only leave $r$ behind?

Comment: $x^2 + z^2 +y^2 = 2$ does not imply $x+y+z = \sqrt2$. $(x+y+z)^2 = 2$ would mean $x + y + z = \sqrt2$

Comment: Substitute values of $x, y, z$ from spherical coordinates in $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 2$ and simplify.

Comment: Yep, I knew I made a schoolboy error somewhere, I always do. I'll try it now and let you know if I have any better luck, I'm still slightly confused for equation $(1)$ though, I don't think I made an error is substituting values but I'm not sure how they managed to remove all the $sin^2 \theta$ and $cos^2 \theta$ variables, you can divide by $sin^2 \theta$ to sort out the left but then you're left with $cos^2 \theta / sin^2 \theta$ on the right...

Comment: I feel like I'm forgetting a trigonometric identity or something, I feel like $cos^2 \theta / sin^2 \theta$ equals something and I've forgotten what it is

Comment: $\cos\theta / \sin\theta = \cot \theta$ or $\sin\theta / \cos\theta = \tan \theta$, you can use either

Comment: Ok, then am I correct in using this method: On the left we have $r^2 {cos}^2 \rho + r^2 {sin}^2 \rho$, I can factor out $r^2$ to get $r^2({cos}^2 \rho + {sin}^2 \rho)$ and since ${cos}^2 \theta + {sin}^2 \theta = 1$ (Trig identity) I can say that ${cos}^2 \rho + {sin}^2 \rho = 1$ so $r^2 = r^2 \space {cot}^2 \theta$ and so ${cot}^2 \theta = 1$ and I can find $\theta$ then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intersection of $x^2+y^2+z^2=2$ and $z=\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}$ on $OXY$ plane gives $x^2+y^2=1$, so we have circle in first quadrant.

Now let's take spherical coordinates:
\begin{array}{}
x = r \sin \phi \cos \theta;  \\ 
y = r \sin \phi \sin \theta; \\
z = r \cos \phi
\end{array}

From $z$ coordinate bounds $\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}} \leqslant z \leqslant \sqrt{2-x^{2}-y^{2}}$ we have
$$r \sin \phi \leqslant r \cos \phi \leqslant \sqrt{2-r^2 \sin^2 \phi}$$

Left inequality gives $\sin \phi \leqslant \cos \phi$, from which we can obtain $\phi \leqslant \frac{\pi}{4}$. Right inequality gives $r \leqslant \sqrt{2}$.
So for integral in spherical coordinates we have
$$\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\int\limits_{0}^{\sqrt{2}} \underbrace{r^{2} \sin \theta}_{\text{Jacobian}} \cdot \underbrace{r \sin \phi \cos \theta}_{x} \cdot \underbrace{r \sin \phi \sin \theta}_{y} d r  d \phi d \theta$$

Comment: Thanks this is a really good explanation but I'm just a bit confused how you found the Jacobian part, we have $xy$ on the inside of the function so I understand you converted those to spherical coordinates and plugged them in but I'm not sure how to obtain the Jacobian term.

Comment: Thank you also. Jacobian come from general variables substitution formula for multivariable integrals. Look, for example, https://www.imomath.com/index.php?options=484&lmm=0 or any book for multivariable integrals.

Comment: Oh ok, I have one more question that's slightly unrelated to what you've posted. In my question I showed that the answer for equation $(1)$ was given as $r^2 cos^2{\rho} = r^2 sin^2{\rho}$ but I don't get this when I substitute in my $x,y,z$ values, here's what I do: $z^2 = x^2 +y^2$ becomes $r^2 cos^2{\theta} = r^2 cos^2{\rho} sin^2{\theta} + r^2 sin^2{\rho} sin^2{\theta}$, i factor out $r^2 sin^2{\theta}$: $r^2 cos^2{\theta} = r^2 sin^2{\theta} (cos^2{\rho} + sin^2{\rho})$ and I know $cos^2{\rho} + sin^2{\rho} = 1$(Trig identity) so my final answer is: $r^2 cos^2{\theta} = r^2 sin^2{\theta}$

Comment: How do they get $r^2 cos^2{\rho} = r^2 sin^2{\rho}$ instead of $\theta$?

Comment: May be it's more appropriate, that you open new question, as you wrote "that's slightly unrelated ", and I'll try to help you there. Only paste, please, link here.

Comment: Oh no that's not what I meant, It's still completely related to my question it's just not the method you used. Since it isn't the method you used I wouldn't usually have asked you but I saw you just reply to me so I thought I could catch you while you're on here to quickly check if there's any mistakes in my working?

Comment: I do, however, have a question that IS related to your answer/method. I tried doing this method when I first got the question but I thought we could only set up $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leqslant z \leqslant \sqrt{2-x^2-y^2}$ if our initial triple integral had $dz$ as the innermost integral, since in this case we have $dz$ as the outermost integral I didn't think we could set up $z$ in the way you have, or does the order of $dxdydz$ not matter?

Comment: Order of variables, of course, matter and there are different approaches in different sources. In your case I understand, that $x \in [0,1]$, $y \in [0, \sqrt{1-x^2}] $ and $z$ as you wrote.

Comment: But if $z$ is the outermost integral (Given by the fact they've written the triple integral as $dxdydz$) then doesn't that mean $z$ should be defined by ${\int_0}^1$ and $x$ should be defined by the innermost integral?

Comment: For $z$ to be defined as you've given, should the order of the integrals not have to be $dzdydx$ and not $dxdydz$?

Comment: I might be missing something because the answers you give match with the answers on my solution sheet but I just don't understand how $z$ gets defined with those bounds if it isn't the innermost integral

Comment: Order of variables, in this case, coincides with order of integrals(not reverse): most left integral is with $[0,1]$ and most left variable is $x$, then goes $y$ and so on.